# Duplicate notifications - react-native-push-notification

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

I have a problem with react-native-push-notification module on Android. After correct set up the notifications are delivered for generated device token. Unfortunately, every push notification is duplicated.

At that moment I do not implement the channel name and the remote push notification is delivered twice to **"Other"** category. When there is a channel name Android displays the push notification as **"Other"** and **"Category Name"** in the Notification Module.

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
                android:value="Channel Name"/>
<meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
                android:value="Channel description"/>
```

Is there any possibility to leave only one push notification. I am sure that push notification is sent once.

I know that the library is not supported but unfortunately I do not have time for a change. I need a quick fix.

I will be glad for help!

Comment: Are they being duplicated on both Android and iOS? Or only one platform?

Comment: This app is made only for Android and I could not test it on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also was going through same problem,
Then i realized there was misunderstanding in the documentation.

How i solved it?

Go to AndroidManifest.xml and remove this :-

```
<!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
<!-- < Only if you're using GCM or localNotificationSchedule() > -->
```

Only one receiver is required while the library has mentioned 2 receivers so remove this one to stop receiving the duplicate notification.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, double-notification-in-tray, problem in my React Native app.

It happened because I registered TWO channels for notifications with `PushNotification.createChannel({...})`.

So, all I had to do was to call `PushNotification.deleteChannel('DUPLICATE_CHANNEL_ID')` for the unnecessary channel. I called the dfelete method only once, in my notification-configuration upon app start-up.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #  Copy the below code it will work #

React.useEffect(() => {
  PushNotification.getChannels(function (channel_ids) {
    channel_ids.forEach((id) => {
      PushNotification.deleteChannel(id)
    })
  });
  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: "channel-id", // (required)
      channelName: "your_channel_name", // (required)
      channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
      playSound: true, // (optional) default: tru
      importance: Importance.HIGH, // (optional) default: Importance.HIGH. Int value of the Android notification importance
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration pattern if true.
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );

}, []);

// this should be outside of useEffect()
// delete default channel_id "fcm_fallback_notification_channel"
PushNotification.getChannels(function (channel_ids) {
  console.log(channel_ids)
  PushNotification.deleteChannel('fcm_fallback_notification_channel')
  });
```